# How do I retrieve certificate definition in Azure Synapse dedicated pool?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I have created certificate with following definition. The certificate is created .Is there   any option to retrieve certificate definition from  system objects ?If we can retrieve definition ,what is the best way to restrict user to view create certificate definition?

I checked sys.sql_modules table but couldn't find anything

`CREATE CERTIFICATE xxxx_Certificate    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y'  WITH SUBJECT = 'YYYY Information',    EXPIRY_DATE = '20221231'`;

Regards,
Rajib

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no proper way retrieve Azure key vault secret using T-SQL.
We can retrieve key vault secret using Py spark code in Synapse pool.
I created Azure key vault and created secret.
Image for reference:

[image]

value of secret:

[image]

I created synapse analytics and opened synapse studio and created notebook as mentioned below

[image]

I executed below code to retrieve the value of secret.

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils
mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret('<keyvault_name>' , '<secret_name>')
```

I got the azure key vault value.

[image]

you can follow this way to retrieve secret value from Azure key vault.